# Volume of a Solid of Revolution?

Tags: calculus, integration, area, curves, solid-of-revolution

Fairly quick question, but I'm a bit confused on whether or not the work I did was in any way right.
So the question went something like this:
"Find the volume if the region enclosing $y=x^3, x=0,$ and $y=8$ is rotated about the given line.
So the axis of rotation that was given was the y axis, but I'm a bit confused on what the given bounds of $y=8$ and $x=0$ have to do with it, but I pretty much ignored them and put the given equation in terms of $y$ and used the integral $\int^7_0(2^2-(\sqrt[3]{y})^2)$ to solve, is this at all right? Any help would be appreciated
Also looking for some guidance on how I'd go about finding the volume if the axis of rotation was something like $x=6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the best approach to solving these types of problems is sketching out the region in question.  So, we are dealing with the following [region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APQWg.png)

Now, we can go about finding the volume.  Since we are revolving around the y-axis, we can use the following formula:
$$ V = \int_a^b A(y) dy$$

And, we know that $A(y) = \pi((\text{outer radius})^2 - (\text{inner radius})^2)$, where the radius is just the distance from the curve to the axis of rotation.

Since the axis of rotation is the y-axis (equivalently, x = 0), we know that are distances must be x-distances, so we must solve our y-functions in terms of x.

Our outer radius is just the distance from the curve $y = x^3$ to the y-axis, we  which is given by $y^{1/3} - 0 = y^{1/3}$.

Our inner radius is the distance from the y-axis to itself, which is 0.

Therefore, the expression for the area in terms of y is:
$$ A(y) = \pi( (y^{1/3})^2 - (0)^2 ) = \pi(y^{2/3}) $$

Now, we just need to plug back into the equation for the volume, and figure out the bounds.  Since this is a $dy$ integral, we need to know the y-bound.  From the region, we can see that the integral should go from 0 to 8, since the region is bounded by $y = 0$ and $y = 8$.

Therefore, our integral becomes:
$$ V = \int_0^8 \pi(y^{2/3}) dy $$

If the axis of rotation changes, you just need to change your expression for the area.  For example, for an axis of rotation of $x = 6$, you can keep the area in terms of $y$, but now your inner and outer radii expressions will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $y=x^3, \>x=0$ and $y=8$ only specify the area to be rotated. The volume is then defined by rotating this area around a given axis.

For instance, if the axis of rotation is $x=6$, the volume can be integrated with the disk method

$$\int_0^8 \pi[6^2-(6-\sqrt[3]y)^2]dy$$